# How to combine two separate aggregations together in same result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to take two aggregations and combine them together. "Blakes Seven" kindly helped me with a couple of queries to retrieve first and second array element values but I need the two together.

First one:

```
db.getCollection('anothertest').aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$a" },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "first": { "$first": "$a" }
}}
])
```

Give a result of:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439"),
        "first" : 4
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Second one:

```
db.getCollection('anothertest').aggregate([
{ "$unwind": "$a" },
// Keeps the first element
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "first": { "$first": "$a" },
    "a": { "$push": "$a" }
 }},
{ "$unwind": "$a" }
,
// Removes the first element
{ "$redact": {
"$cond":{
"if": { "$ne": [ "$first", "$a" ] },
"then": "$$KEEP",
  "else": "$$PRUNE"
}
}}
```

Gives the result:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439"),
        "second" : 2
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

What I need is the result of:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439"),
        "first" : 4
        "second" : 2
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

In addition to this, the document it is based on is just an example where the values sit as elements within an array. How would I use this on a nested array? If this is all to complicated for Aggregation, maybe there is an easier way to achieve this using Map Reduce? Thanks for any help provided.

The document for the above is below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439"),
"a" : [ 
    4, 
    2, 
    8, 
    71, 
    21
]
}
```

**UPDATE TO MY ORIGINAL POST**
I have now managed to take the awesome script and make it work for my document which has nested arrays - up to a point.

```
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Profit & Loss"}},
{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" },
        { "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" },
        { "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" },
        { "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells" },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "first": { "$first": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" },
    "a": { "$push": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
}},
{ "$unwind": "$a" },
{"$skip":1},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "BalanceName": { "$first": "$first" },
    "BalanceValue": { "$first":      "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" },
}}
])
```

Actually, accidentally I forgot to update the second $unwind so it remained as "$a". and what happened was I got the following result:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("564d12da1506995581569428"),
        "BalanceName" : "Sales",
        "BalanceValue" : null
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

But when I changed the $unwind to match the $unwind for the first value, I get no results at all. I cannot understand why, any ideas? Thanks, Matt

Comment: Matt, please don't edit your original asking post with different different questions than the one originally written. If you have additional problems ask them separately in a new question. Reading StackOverflow help section will make it clear for you on how to ask good questions, which directly affects the probability of getting good answers.

Comment: I will give it a read, thanks. The problem was that I had tried out as per an answer and then realised that it needed further clarification with a bit of explanation. I went to create a new answer and I was advised against answering my own question, even though it wasn't an answer but rather a progression from the first answer. What I wanted to add would not have fit into a comment. So rather than create a new post for no reason, I edited the original post and made it clear where I added additional content rather than edit. Apologies if this breaks protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that following the same logic as the first aggregation you posted. Note that I used [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) to skip the first array element and get the second.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "_id": ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439")
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "first": { "$first": "$a" },
        "a": { "$push": "$a" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    {"$skip":1},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "first": { "$first": "$first" },
        "second": { "$first": "$a" },
    }}
])
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439"),
    "first" : 4,
    "second" : 2 
}
```

Your second aggregation is also quite close to the desired output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "_id": ObjectId("565cc5261506995581569439")
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "first": { "$first": "$a" },
        "a": { "$push": "$a" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$a" },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond":{
        "if": { "$ne": [ "$first", "$a" ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }}},
    { "$limit": 1},
    { "$project": {
        "_id":1,
        "first":1,
        "second":"$a"
    }}
])
```

**EDIT:** Also, as they are, both aggregations only work for a single document, thus the necessity to add the initial [$match](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) step.

Comment: fantastic! Thanks for your help, I will check it out in full now and give you some feedback, very much appreciated!

Comment: this works really well where there is one document to process. I added a second document with different numbers and it came back with two results. The second result was my new document which had done first and second perfectly. However, result one values for first and second are the value of first.

Comment: also on my one (the one you fixed up at the bottom) if I change {limit} to 2 so I can see the results of both my documents, it has done a very similar thing to the other script. This time, the second result is correct for [first] and [second]. The first result has the same value [first] as the second result. Any idea why the results either seem unreliable or don't work on more than one document at a time. If I remove limit altogether, I end up with 7 results with only one of the array sets correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, you can't remove /change the *$limit* because you just flattened the *a* array with *$unwind*. Do read the mongoDB docs page to understand what is happening in each pipeline stage.